# Which major scale patterns to study?

Tags: guitar, learning, scales

So I'm very confused I found 3 different systems for the major scale which are:

- the caged system
- sweeping pattern (7 3nps patterns)
- conventional patterns (7 patterns)

I've never heard of the conventional pattern except from grimoire guitar series so I don't know which is more important.

Answer (score 4):

At the end of the day they are all the same scales just the application to learn them is different. Every system has it's own uses and reasons.

- The CAGED system gets you to focus on how the different barre chords
  you play and the pentatonic scales they are related to line up.
- The sweeping patterns is thinking of the scales in terms of the sweeping lead guitar technique.
- The conventional pattern is just the standard way to build a scale and the patterns that relate to it.

At the end of the day they all teach the same thing and there are benefits of looking at the scales each way, but depending on what you want to do one may be more optimal to focus on. For example, if you don't plan on using sweeps in your solos, learning the sweep patterns doesn't really make much sense and if you're not going to be playing very many barre chords the CAGED system isn't really the best way to start learning.

Comment: But I also find that a lot of patterns differ in order from book to another and I have no clue why

Comment: @StevieRay it's just they are different patterns,  but at the end of the day the notes are the same.